# Interpretation and symbolic notations of operations in mathematics

Tags: logic, terminology

As we know a mathematical operation is a function. And a function is a special type of relation. Ultimately a relation is a set of ordered pairs.
For example, what is addition of natural numbers? At the most abstract level, addition is a functional relation=correspondence between an ordered set (a,b) of two natural numbers and another number c. So in a rigorous way  addition is just a set containing elements of the form ((a,b),c) for example:
+={....; ((1,2),3); ((2,3),5); ((7,0),7),...}
Here we can say that c is the sum of a and b in this order (the order should not matter because of commutativity )

So why it is addition viewed by almost everyone  as a "process" with a "result"? What in the world is a "process" in mathematics? Can be the notion of "mathematical process" be rigorously defined? I don;t see how...
And if we want, we could even critique the writing "1+2=3"?? We know very well what "3" is, but what  is "1+2"?? What type of mathematical object is that? How can  a mathematical object be equal to a combination" of two other objects?  Oh, we say 1+2  is just a "symbolic expression" or just another "name" for 3... i find this a bit unsatisfying from a highly rigorous point of view.
Even some mathematicians when seeing "1+2=3" think like this: well we have a process of adding 1 and 2 and we get three... i don;t like this interpretation. At all! 
Others even say "that is the performing of a computation"...What the heck? So on the left side we have an "unperformed computation" and on the right side a result?? What's a performed and unperformed computation?? How can be something unperformed equal to other something??
How can a single object be equal to a combination of other two objects?? As in 1+2=3
And then, shouldn't 1+2=3 be different than "1+2=3+0"?? In the latter we have an equality of two "combinations", in the first we have an equality between a single combination and its result... from a highly rigorous point of view the tqo equal signs "Act" a bit different.

So if we want complete rigor in math, statements as "1+2=3" lack it a bit... because "1+2" and "3" should be of different types, so how can they be equal?

So my questions are:
1) Speaking from a purely SYNTACTICAL point of view, how should we rigorously define what a "combination" of two mathematical objects is, for example two numbers? If  1,2,3,... are a "type" of math objects, shouldn't  "1+2" be of another type??

2) How can two things be equal if they are of different types? For example in 1+2=3, LHS is a "combination" of two numbers and RHS is a single number... how can they be treated as equal, having different types?

Comment: A "process" in math can be modelled as a [computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation) and we have [Computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory).

Comment: Why ""1+2" and "3" should be of different types" ? They are *arithmetical terms*, i.e. "names" for number.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think here "1+2"is the (or _a_) "process" statement of "3".

Comment: What's a "process statement"?

Comment: See Girard's book "Proofs and Types" http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf  Page 1, "Section 1.1 Sense and denotation in logic", discusses >>exactly<< your example (including whether we should consider the operation as a graph, in the traditional Dirichlet sense,  or as a process).

Comment: " Ultimately a relation is a set of ordered pairs." No, this is not true. A relation is *modeled within set theory as a set of ordered pairs.* You are confusing the territory with the map. The number 2 is MODELED AS the set {0,1}. But the number 2 is not a set. See for example Benacerraf, What Numbers Could Not Be.

Comment: Oh, and what is a relation then?? ... What is the definition of "modeled as"??

Comment: In every math book i have read a relation is defined exactly as a subset of a cartesian product AxB. So i don;t know what you're talking about. This is a rigorous and crystal clear mathematical definition, i cannot find any flaws in it.  On the contrary, viewing an operation as a "process" is something quite silly i think. Actually i am starting to believe that the reason why many children loose interest in mathematics almost immediately after basic arithmetic and computations is exactly the way we teach them that operations such as addition are "processes"...

Comment: And about what you are talking with number modelation, actually the number 2 can be modeled in multiple ways but speaking abstractly all models are the same, exactly in an isomorphism. And no, in mathematics we don;t have maps and territories, because mathematics is not a material, concrete piece of land, it is abstract.

Comment: @amarius8312 It's helpful if you reference my handle with an '@' sign when you reply to me so that I get notified. I gave you the standard reference for your questions, namely Benacerraf. If you truly don't understand the difference between a mathematical model of a thing and the thing itself, you should ponder that. I admit that when the things are themselves mathematical objects, the discussion becomes even more subtle. Still, a number is not a set. A number is modeled within set theory as a set.

Comment: @user4894 What you say is not on-topic. The discussion is not about numbers being or not being sets.

Comment: @amarius8312: If you want to discuss something, please use chat. If you want to suggest improvements or point out weaknesses in answers, make a comment. Answers are not to be used to refer to comments or answers, but solely to answer the question as exhaustively as possible.

Comment: I am deleting my answers and moving to close the question.  There is no productive answer allowed.

Answer (score 2):

See [First-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) for the syntactical specifications of the formal language dealing with *natural numbers*.

The basic arithmetical symbols are : **0** (an individual constant denoting the number *zero*), the unary *successor* function **s(x)**, and two binary functions : **+** and **x** for the numerical operations of *sum* and *product*.

The axioms are the first-order version of [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation).

The usual numerical symbols (the *numerals*) : **1, 2, 3**, ... are introduced as abbreviations :

> **1=s(0)**, i.e. "**1** is the name for the (unique) successor of the number *zero*";
>
> **2=s(1)=s(s(0))**, and so on.

Using the axioms, we prove that :

> > **1+2=3** [which abbreviates : **s(0)+s(s(0))=s(s(s(0)))**].

Comment: Same questions as I have for the OP. Sure, that's how we model 1 + 2 = 3 using the Peano axioms. But 1 + 2 = 3 tells us something about the world, while simply definining 1 = S0, 2 = S2, and 3 = S2 doesn't. Meaning is lost when we introduce the abstract mathematical model. I believe that's a problem for the OP's question and also for your answer. This seems to be the heart of the philosophical issue. Abstract models have no meaning. And that's significant. What am I missing?

Comment: No, 1+2=3 tells no more about the world than a mere "link" aka relation between the 3 numbers 1,2 and 3.  Of course this link is not arbitrary, it is based on modelling many things happening in reality, but it is no more than a simple link. And, the defining 1=S0 ,2=S1 etc captures the very essence of counting one by one.

Comment: @user4894 - of course, Peano's axioms are an "abstraction"... but an abstraction of the "real" counting process. We name *two* the number following *one*; then we nane *three* the number following *two*, and so on. The "following" procedure is exactly what is formalized by the *successor* funtion.

Comment: This doesn't really address the underlying problem here or either of the explicit questions.  What is the point of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've found two interesting papers about this issue:
1) Gottlob Frege's "On sense and denotation"
https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/453/FregeDisplay.pdf

2)Alonzo Church Introduction to mathematical logic (in the introductory chapter about "Names")
http://www.hist-analytic.com/ChurchIntroductionIntroduction.pdf

They treat exactly what i asked in a very nice way.

Thanks to @John Forkosh who suggested above the "sense-denotation " duality. It's been a long time since i've reflected about this philosophical issue, and it seemed untractable. But know i've cleared it.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my attempt at a simpler answer, without the need for math:

Your problem arises from your interpretation of equality. You are interpreting = to mean "The thing on the left of the sign is equal in all qualities to the thing on the right, while in math a = sign only signifies that the things on both sides of the sign represent the same quantity.

Likewise, in other fields of math, the equal-sign only compares specific qualities of the things representated by the notation (e.g. that two sets contain the same elements).

Comment: The vast majority of modern math has nothing to do with quantity

Comment: @jobermark If you give me an example, I'll be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: The whole of set theory, abstract algebra, topology, symbolic logic, even, perhaps ironically computation theory itself, have to do with what patterns of permutations fit together.  Those are not about quantity in the same way the older branches of math like analysis.  Since the mid-20th century most of the math done follows from what is left of geometry once you remove measurement and focus on abstract patterns.  Since most of math has older roots, it is still about quantities, but most of what is currently being done in math no longer fits into that mold.

Comment: You and the OP are on opposite ends of a continuum where the ansser is in the middle.  A lot of what people compute is not numeric.   He resents that the focus on computation is even a part of the system.  Older views of math focus on numbers as the kinds of things you compute, as a goal, instead of as an incidental part of computing that is focused on some other problem.

Comment: jobemark, do you have math studies? do you currently do math? Or only philosophy?

Comment: I think the poster here is right, but the term "quantity" is not well chosen. He just speaks about sense and reference. A=B means that A and B are two "senses"(aka descriptions) of the same reference= "thing" or mathematical object. Not necessarily a number, interpreted as a "quantity". You are right about modern math having nothing to do with the idea of quantity. Actually exactly this was what i missed when asking the initial question, the distinction between sense and reference.  That's why the question is answered from my point of view.

Comment: @amarius8312  1) Unless you expect everyone here to demonstrate credentials, that is an ad hominem attack masquerading as a question.  2) I am not dealing with you further as long as all you have to offer is assumptions and opinions.